# php string comparison not working for image metadata

Tags: php, metadata

I am extracting image metadata using php. The logic of my below code is that if the user uploads the default file with metadata(UserComment)=ASCIIsd11, he/she will get an error.

```
<?php
$exif_s = exif_read_data('e42889ed00.jpg');
$phtchk = $exif_s["UserComment"];
print $phtchk;
print strcmp($phtchk, "ASCIIsd11");
if(strcmp($phtchk, "ASCIIsd11") == 0){ echo "You have not uploaded your own photo"; exit;} 
else
{
echo"You have uploaded it.";
}
?>
```

`print $phtchk;` returns `ASCIIsd11`

`print strcmp($phtchk, "ASCIIsd11");` returns `-1`

and the last echo statement `"You have uploaded it"` is printed. Actually I am expecting `strcmp()` to return `0`. Kindly help.

Comment: Do `var_dump($phtchk)` to check what the variable really consists of.

Answer (score 0):

Do `var_dump(phtchk);` instead of `print $phtchk;`
Perhaps you don't see some extra-chars (eg: `\n`).

If it concerns the collation, you should see:
[UTF-8 characters not displaying properly from JPEG IPTC data in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785186/utf-8-characters-not-displaying-properly-from-jpeg-iptc-data-in-php)